# Programmatically block git push?

Tags: git, credentials, githooks, git-push

Is the any way to block `git push` under certain conditions?

For instance, if any of the files being pushed contain words that indicate confidential material, such as `aws_secret_key_id`, `password`, `bank account` or similar, is there any way to automatically reject the push?

Comment: Have you looked into git hooks?  You'd need something on the server side, but you could reject a push there.

Comment: No, but I will check it out.  Thanks!